# Modify an element of a Dataset

Tags: dataset

I have a Dataset of states and I need to modify a variable: 
`States = Dataset[{<|"StateId" -> {Bt, 1, 1.15, q}, "B" -> Bt, "RC" -> "n", "Es" -> "n", "NC" -> Null,"e" -> N123|>}]`

As of now I'm able to modify an entrance, for example "e" with this code: `States = States[All, If[#StateId == {Bt, 1, 1.15, 2}, <|#, "e" -> "New element"|>, #] &]`.

I was wondering if there is a way to take the previous element: N123 in my case, and adding 1 (or other simple operations) so that I get N123+1 in the entrance "e", without using a Query.

Answer (score 2):

`States = States[All, If[#StateId == {Bt, 1, 1.15, 2}, <|#, "e" -> #e+1|>, #]&]`
works.